# "You have reached your question limit" issue

Tags: support

I am not sure why I can't create new question for software engineering stack exchange. The message is "You have reached your question limit". It has been a week.

[image]

Comment: Can you take a screenshot of the error and add it to this question? Or confirm the exact wording of the message? There are a few different limits that you may be hitting, so the exact wording and context is important.

Comment: Okay sure. I have just added the screenshot. But, I can post question for stackoverflow and codereview

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Think someone's reputation on Stack Overflow should prevent them from being banned on programmers](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6639/think-someones-reputation-on-stack-overflow-should-prevent-them-from-being-bann)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why am I getting “Sorry, we are no longer accepting questions from this account”?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3041/why-am-i-getting-sorry-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-from-this-account)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you click on the "the Help Center" link, you will be brought to [this page, which describes why questions are no longer being accepted from your account](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/help/question-bans).

Looking at your profile, it looks like you have triggered this automatic question block and there's nothing that we can do manually to reverse it.

These blocks are triggered by asking questions that are downvoted and closed. Looking at the questions that you've asked, I see 14 questions. There are 4 deleted and 10 not deleted. In total, 7 have a net negative score, 3 have a net positive score, and 4 have a 0 score. The net vote total looks like -10 across all of the questions.

The best advice that I can offer is that you can look through the questions you've asked and attempt to edit them to improve the problems. Not all questions can be salvaged, though. Questions that have already been answered are more difficult to improve without invalidating existing answers. Questions that are entirely off-topic are also difficult to improve. If you can't find any questions to improve, I'd recommend looking for questions that you can write answers to - writing good answers, getting upvotes, and demonstrating an understanding of the community scope and expectations may allow the automatic block to expire sooner.

I would advise against posting questions on Stack Overflow or Code Review that are off-topic there just because you are blocked here. Questions cannot be migrated to a site where you have an automatic question block. In addition, if those questions are downvoted, closed, and/or deleted, you may trigger the automatic blocks there as well.