# Deleting low rated question to bypass the "You have reached your limit of questions"

Tags: support

I looked at [this](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9122/you-have-reached-your-question-limit-issue) and wondering if I can delete my negative rated questions to ask another question, since there seems to be an arbitrary limit being imposed by what ever measure that might be, so deleting a question to ask another question seems to should do the trick.

Regarding "there is no manual way to by pass the automatic trigger for question limit", it is sad that a software engineering site has decided to go with line "but system won't allow me to do what is needed so though luck", with that mind set it would better not be bothered with such a site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I looked at this and wondering if I can delete my negative rated
> questions to ask another question, since there seems to be an
> arbitrary limit being imposed by what ever measure that might be, so
> deleting a question to ask another question seems to should do the
> trick.

No. Deleted posts are still inputs into the algorithm that determines if you have a question ban. Making good contributions, receiving up votes on those, and waiting is the only way to get out of a question (or answer) block.

> Regarding "there is no manual way to by pass the automatic trigger for
> question limit", it is sad that a software engineering site has
> decided to go with line "but system won't allow me to do what is
> needed so though luck", with that mind set it would better not be
> bothered with such a site.

The intention is to make sure that before you "both with such a site", you spend a little bit of time understanding the culture, rules, and norms of the community behind the site.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, regarding waiting time, my last question was d 1 year, 1 month ago ( according to the site ), so how long more am I suppose to wait?

Comment: @jimjim That is not correct. You [asked a question on August 11](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/414700/handle-replicated-web-requests-only-once). This question was down voted and deleted, so it contributes to the question block.

Comment: Thank you, forgot about that one,  was going to delete another question to be able to ask a question. I retrofitted it to become a new question. At some point the downvoted questions can become good questions that might get upvoted, who knew!

Comment: @jimjim: this question from August 11 is a third-party resource request. As explained in our [help center](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), such questions are off-topic here, and we have a predefined close reason for them. So don't be astonished if it will get more downvotes and close votes, soon.

Comment: @DocBrown : Thank you for the heads up Doc, people like you take the pain away. Also thanks for the flux capacitors.